# pipenv multiple versions of python installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pipenv

I currently have python 3.6 and 3.7 installed on my PC and I want to run `pipenv` with `python 3.7`.  The only issue is that in my python 3.7 folder, my executable for python 3.7 is `python37.exe`, so everytime I run a command with python 3.7 I have to call `python37 -m pip "some command"`.

I was able to create a virtual environment with pipenv by running the command:

`pipenv install --python C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.exe`

But now when I try to install the dependencies its calling `python.exe` instead of `python37.exe`. I get this error when I run `pipenv install`:

No Python at  `C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe`

Comment: As far as I know, pipenv is a packaging tool. Correct me if I'm wrong. Why aren't you using virtualenv for creating virtual environment?

Comment: pipenv uses virtualenv for creating virtual environments, but also always package management

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge. I looked at my python installation folder, the execution file is named as python.exe without 37 or 38 in the name. So why don't you rename your python37.exe to python.exe and give a try

Comment: using python.exe for python 3.6

Comment: Rename python37.exe back to python.exe. Create shortcuts for both 3.6 and 3.7 exe and rename them to python36.exe python37.exe or whatever you want. Point these shortcuts to PATH variable, then you can easily run with CMD and also pipenv can detect the original python.exe

Comment: When you *first* created your pipenv env, did you pass in the `--python /path/to/python37.exe`? Or are you only doing this now? What is the output of `pipenv --py`?

Comment: yes, I did pass in the path for my python37.exe, and my output to `pipenv --py` is:
`C:\Users\MyUserName\.virtualenvs\random-4XfPx90F\Scripts\python.exe`